IE custom protocol handler to open chrome not working
I have an MVC 4.0 website that runs on IE. One of the links on the web page opens in Chrome. Until today we had chrome version 80 on our servers and in order to open chrome from IE we used a custom protocol handler in the registry. Now it stopped working. Is there another way to open chrome from IE and send a URL with few parameters? Any idea why the newer version of chrome won't work with the same custom protocol it did before?
